# getting value of sensor each second c++

Tags: c++, mysql, database, unix-timestamp

I am recently trying to store data measured by my humidity sensor into my MYSQL database. I have already programmed the necessary C++ pogramm getting the data from the sensor, storing it in my MYSQL database and getting the current UnixTime as well.

However, I´d like to store the data each second and think using a thread does not seem a neat solution for this problem. I also do not want MYSQL to insert the UnixTime automatically. I´d like to keep on using my C++ programm for that.

Does anybody know an easier approach to store the data each second with the necesarry UnixTime using C++?

Comment: You don't need an explicit thread - just sleep for a second between each reading. You can get the time with std::time().

Comment: But what if my code is longer. Let´s say I got 200 lines of code before I ask my sensor for the data. If a sleep 1 second then I won´t receive each second a value. Is there maybe a way to interrupt such as one exits in C? So whenever the UixTime changes I ask my sensor for data and write it in my database?

Comment: What are the objections against `std::threads` or even an good old fashioned [fork](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) if you're working under *NIX ? It's the standard way o do things in the background.

Comment: I´m programming C++ only for only a short time. Therefore, I thought there might be an easier approach such as an interrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads are actually a neat solution for background tasks. Consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void everySecondTask() {
  while (true) {
    // Do actual work here, e.g. get sensor data and write to db
    std::cout << "second passed" << std::endl;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  }
}

int main() {
  // operations and sleep in everySecondTask is done in different thread, code
  // in main is not paused.
  std::thread background(everySecondTask);

  // do you 200 lines of code here, while task is called every second

  background.join();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also use threading to solve this issue. However, I would not rely on one worker thread. What would happen if your process takes longer then 1 second to run?

Instead, I would create a group of worker threads. Have each thread wait on a `std::condition_variable`. This way you're not pulling the status of your threads and instead relying on the conditional variable to be notified once they have work in some work queue.

Answer (score 1):

Having a dedicated thread is fine.  But here's a way to do it without a dedicated thread.  And this technique could also be used with the dedicated thread.

The bottom line is:

**Don't use `sleep_for` for this task**

Use `sleep_until` instead.

You can get the proper wakeup time once.  And then do whatever work you need to do during the loop.  And wake up next time by sleeping until 1s longer than the last wake up time (instead of sleeping for 1s).

Note the English in the above description:  "sleep until" vs "sleep for".

Here's code to make this concrete:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <thread>

std::mt19937_64 eng;

void
do_other_work()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    static uniform_int_distribution<> dist{2, 600};
    this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds{dist(eng)});
}

std::pair<double, date::sys_seconds>
get_humidity()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    static uniform_real_distribution<> dist;
    return {dist(eng), round<seconds>(system_clock::now())};
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    auto wakeup = system_clock::now() + 1s;
    while (true)
    {
        auto data = get_humidity();
        cout << data.first << " : " << data.second << '\n';
        do_other_work();
        this_thread::sleep_until(wakeup);
        wakeup += 1s;
    }
}
```

I've added the [header-only library "date.h"](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) just to make it easy to format your current UnixTime timestamp.  But the take-home point above is to set the `time_point` `wakeup` once with `system_clock::now()`, and then simply increment it by `1s` on each iteration and use `this_thread::sleep_until` to sleep until that `time_point`.  As long as your other work doesn't exceed 1s, this program will reliably output data once per second:

```
0.79 : 2017-01-23 02:06:21
0.40 : 2017-01-23 02:06:22
0.02 : 2017-01-23 02:06:23
0.27 : 2017-01-23 02:06:24
0.14 : 2017-01-23 02:06:25
0.86 : 2017-01-23 02:06:26
...
```

If you want to put `get_humidity()` in another thread, that's still fine.  But to keep an accurate per/sec report within that other thread (which still must do other work), use `sleep_until` instead of `sleep_for` because you don't know how long that other work will take.

Comment: I got a problem when it comes to system_clock::now()+1s   I always get the error unable to find numberic literal operator

Comment: @JayJay: Ah, that means you are using a standard prior to C++14. Not a problem. Substitute seconds{1} for 1s, and you'll be good to go. No functional or performance difference. Just C++14 added that syntactic sugar.